# Redirecting from a namespaced controller using a hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes, namespaces

I have a double namespace situation, where my controllers look like this:

```
CandidateController
Candidate::PerformanceController
Candidate::Performance::ReviewController
```

In Rails 2, I was able to use `redirect_to` from the `Candidate::Performance::ReviewController` controller in order to redirect to an action in the `CandidateController`, like so:

```
class Candidate::Performance::ReviewController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :ensure_manager

  # ...

  def ensure_manager
    if !current_user.manager?
      flash[:warning] = t(:must_be_manager)
      redirect_to :controller => '/candidate', :action => :index
    end
  end
end
```

The `/` in `controller => '/candidate'` would allow Rails to redirect from `app.com/performance/reviews` to `app.com/candidate`.

However, this seems to not work the same in Rails 3.1. Instead, my `redirect_to` goes to `app.com/candidate//candidate`. What is the correct way to specify a "absolute" controller within a `redirect_to` hash (ie. without using a path helper)?

***Update:*** I know this would be infinitely easier if I just use named route helpers (ie. `candidate_path`). Unfortunately, there is a lot of legacy code in our codebase which doesn't use RESTful routing and instead uses the default "catch-all" route; ie. we have a lot of actions with no named route to fallback on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone else runs into this problem, it seems to be a [known issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/2575) (unsure whether they consider it a bug or not, given the lack of response on the issue page from anyone working on Rails).

Until they patch it (assuming they do), I've added the following little monkey patch into an initializer, based on the code given in the original post of that issue:

```
module ActionDispatch
  module Routing
    class RouteSet
      class Generator
        def use_relative_controller_with_absolute_paths!
          return if controller.starts_with?('/')
          use_relative_controller_without_absolute_paths!
        end

        alias_method_chain :use_relative_controller!, :absolute_paths
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Hope this can help someone else!

**Update**: It seems that this was fixed in Rails [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/4908).

Comment: Just found the same post when looking for the doc :) I guess the url_for I was looking at in the doc was deprecated. http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/url_for

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if something else is wrong. In the doc:

> In particular, a leading slash ensures no namespace is assumed. Thus,
>   while url_for :controller => ‘users‘ may resolve to
>   Admin::UsersController if the current controller lives under that
>   module, url_for :controller => ’/users‘ ensures you link to
>   ::UsersController no matter what.

And I don't think it changed...

Also, shouldn't the catch-all routes be after the default routes in your config?

I think that redirect_to :controller => ... uses url_for to build the url, so in the end, if your custom routes catches /candidates, I don't really see the difference.

---

Some people have the same problem: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/2575

> Patching actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb line 434
>   as follows fixes this: if !named_route && different_controller? &&
>   !controller.starts_with?('/')

Comment: My catch-all route is at the bottom of my routes.rb file.

Comment: Ok, so what's the problem with using the candidate_url helper again?

Comment: Because that was just an example. There are other similar instances (using `url_for`/`redirect_to`/`link_to`) to routes that aren't named so I can't rely on it.

Comment: Well, according to the doc, it should work I think. I hope someone else can help you.

Comment: Can you link me the doc you're looking at?